# Нет звука на компьютере. Проблема с драйвером IDT High Definition Audio CODEC

Tags: windows-7, аудио, драйвер

Добрый день!

На домашнем компьютере пропал звук. Компьютер родителей, поэтому, кто что устанавливал/ удалял доподлинно неизвестно.

"Никто ничего не делал, оно само", как обычно :)

При изучении проблемы обнаружила, что в Диспетчере устройств драйвер IDT High Definition Audio CODEC отмечен восклицательным знаком.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сначала запустила автоматическую проверку. Сразу скажу, что толку 0 было.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем скачала драйвер самостоятельно и попробовала его установить в ручную, на что получила сообщение, что в обновлении он не нуждается. оО

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой или знает, что надо делать, буду благодарна за любую информацию.

Подробная инфа о системе
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Найти и скачать драйвера с сайта Intel. Там у них ещё программка была, которая проверяет компьютер и сама скачивает и устанавливает все необходимые их драйвера

Comment: посмотрела, ничего не нашел.
http://saveimg.ru/show-image.php?id=c99f6ea455dcfa3ccdbdaa3e67575428

Comment: Не знаю почему подумал что это Intel, Когда написано IDT, Короче они больше не занимаются audio-чипами. А контора, которая вместо них продолжает их дело, драйвера не раздаёт. Остаётся искать драйвер у производителя материнской платы. Если и с этим облом, то полно всяких помоек с драйверами и вирусами. Ищется всё по тому же vendor_id+device_id

Comment: На закладке `сведения` выбрать свойство `ИД Оборудования`. Смотреть на VEN_1234&DEV_1234 1234 - какие-то цифры в шестнадцатеричном формате. VEN - vendor_id, DEV - device_id

Comment: Да, я сейчас так и ищу. зашла на сайт devid.info, там по ИД нашла драйвера. Они стали, ошибка в Диспетчере устройств пропала, но звук так и не появился. Теперь, когда нажимаешь на динамик в правом нижнем углу с красным крестиком, просто появляется уведомление, что звуковое устройство не подключено. Примечательно, что пару недель назад все работало.

Comment: У вас же вон ещё nvideo аудио осталось.

Comment: Серега! Ты супер красавчик, я все сделала! :) По ИД на форуме нашла драва и туда, и туда. Вот ссыль, если кто-то будет искать https://ddriver.ru/kms_downloads+index+action-id+cat-18+ids-73+idd-6.html